# Is it Possible To Perform Concurrent Processing in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, plinq

I'd like to ask you is it possible to use parallel programming in ASP.NET 4? For example PLINQ.

(Because all hosting servers are multi-cores now and will it give better perfomance?)

Comment: No, it's not possible. Microsoft realized that web hosting companies don't use multi-core servers, so they deliberately prevented PLINQ from working in ASP.NET sites.

Comment: @John stop fooling around. :)

Comment: @john what? where you know this from? I wanted to use this in some services on our server...

Comment: @Luke, @user624274, @Filip Ekberg, don't you have little sense of humour :-)?

Comment: @All: apparently, humor is lacking around here. I thought it was obvious that my statement was absurd.

Comment: @RobinMaben: No, and this is not a good use of comments. Please delete your comment, and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. But in doubt it makes sense in the most cases. ASP.NET is already highly parallelized, as every request works in it's own thread. If you spin off other threads to do some of the work, that would  create overhead. This overhead will slow down other threads working on other requests. Then again, you will introduce another overhead when synchronizing the results to finish the request. Also this overhead will probably slow down the time required to answer the request.

There might be scenarios where that actually would help increase overall performance, but I think in general it's not worth it.

Of course only stress tests with both approaches would make sure if its more efficient to go with PLINQ or to not use it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES.

Why would you think otherwise? (Hence the sarcastic comments.)

Note, unless you take special steps every HTTP request needs to be completed on the thread that starts serving it. The special steps involve telling ASP.NET to use asynchronous processing for pages which allows a response to be created and the request to be completed on a different threads (with, potentially, intermediate processing other other threads). If you use TPL (including PLINQ) from the request's original thread this is not a problem.